# Using Node.js/Express.js, what's the best way to implement user authentication across two servers?

Tags: node.js, express, server, socket.io

My setup is the following.
I have one node/express web server (S1) which shows all my web sites and implements some kind of user authentication.
From one of the web sites on S1, I want to access/redirect to my other node/express/socket.io server (S2) which relies more on the socket.io api. 
How do I best connect to S2 using the user credentials already obtained and verified by S1? More specifically, I do not want to send the user credentials over the queryString and I don't know how to get access to the user credentials/request parameters by the socket.id).

Answer (score 0):

Token based authentication is a typical solution. JWT based tokens will work very well here. With the user sign-in you generate the JWT token which includes some form of user-id. Then send the JWT to your S2 server (via Authorization header for example). The S2 server will check token signature and get the user-id of it. Some suggestions regarding JWTs:

1) Best is to use RSA based signature. You distribute a public key to S2 so S2 can verify only. And only S1 will be able to sign.

2) Try to avoid including sensitive data. The user-id is probably fine, but user-email probably not.

If not JWT then opaque tokens is another option. In this case you would have to build another "introspect" endpoint on S1 which will validate the token. Then S2 will use it to check if the token is valid. Opaque tokens are usually used in cases where exposing user-id or any other user context related information is not an option at all. Also JWTs tend to be larger than opaque tokens (~1kb over 50-100b) which can be critical in some cases.

Comment: Assuming I will use token based authentication with the token encoded in the queryString, how can I access this token by the socket.id (using the socket.io api)?

Comment: you can use socket middleware (https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-use-fn) and access request variables including headers or queryString. I would use headers as query-string it not secure way.